# Proof Verification: Finite extension is finitely generated

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to prove that given an extension $E$ of a base field $k$, we can find generators $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in E$ such that $E = k(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$.
I want to prove this purely field-theoretically.

**Proof**

- Proof by induction on degree of field extensions $[E : k]$. If the degree is $1$, then $E = k = k(1)$ and we are done.
- Suppose this holds for degree $N$. We wish to prove that an extension $E/k$  of degree  $[E : k] = N+1$ is finitely generated.
- Pick any element $\beta \in E, \beta \not \in k$. Consider the extension $E/k(\beta)$.Since degree is multiplicative, $N + 1 = [E : k] = [E : k(\beta)] [k(\beta) : k]$. Since
  $[k(\beta) : k] > 1$ as the extension is non-trivial, we have $[E : k(\beta)] < [E: k] = N + 1$.
- Since $[E : k(\beta)] < N + 1$, we use the induction hypothesis to find generators $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in k(\beta)$ such that $E = k(\beta)(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$
- This implies that $E = k(\beta, \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n)$, which proves the assertion $\blacksquare$

**Questions**

- Is the above proof correct?
- Is there a slicker proof?

Comment: Yes, there is a slicker proof: take a basis $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ of $E$ over $k$, where $n=[E:k]$; since the $\alpha_i$ generate $E$ as a vector space over $k$, they generate $E$ as an algebra, so $E=k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.